# Which verb form is used when telling about an action that may be completed by some time in the future?

Tags: verbs, future-perfect, future-constructions

"Call me in a week; I may/might HAVE CHANGED my mind by then"

"Call me in a week; I may/might CHANGE my mind by then"

Which version is right? If both are used by native-speakers, why do they choose one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have changed my mind by then

I may change my mind by then

Both are valid, usage depends on the individual. Personally I would say 'might have changed' indicates that its slightly more likely to happen, 'may change' is a little more uncertain, but its very close between the two.

Answer (score 0):

*X might Y* is used to say Y is possible if X chooses or wants Y.  It's unknown if Y will/did actually happen.

> If John wants to take a walk, John might go to the park.

*X may Y* can be used to say X has permission to do Y by someone else, so X choosing Y is a possibility.  It also can mean the same thing as *might*.  It's unknown if Y will/did actually happen.

> John's mother said he may go to the park after dinner.

> If John wants to talk a walk, John may go to the park.

> John's mother said he might go to the park after dinner <- This is not communicating that John's mother gave him permission or that John's mother necessarily approves of this action.

Because of the above, I believe *may* has a sense of being more formal and polite, which is why someone may choose to say *may* over *might* in certain instances, as long as permission is not a concern of the conversation or context.